# Title and author not rendered when providing custom template in Bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I have the following project structure:

```
mybook/
├── _bookdown.yml
├── index.Rmd
├── c1.Rmd
├── c2.Rmd
├── template.tex
```

**File `_bookdown.yml`** is:

```
rmd_files:
- c1.Rmd
- c2.Rmd
output_dir: _out
book_filename: _index_merged.Rmd
```

**File `index.Rmd`** is:

```
---
title: A simple book
author: Andrea Tino
---
```

Files `c1.Rmd` and `c2.Rmd` have trivial content: just a Markdown heading and some text.

**File `template.tex`** is:

```
% !TeX program = pdfLaTeX
\documentclass{monograph}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\author{ $for(authors)$ $authors.name$ \and $endfor$ }
\title{$title$}
$if(subtitle)$
    \subtitle{$subtitle$}
$endif$

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

$body$

\printindex

\end{document}
```

---

#### Problem

When I run this from an R shell (where the working directory is `mybook/`):

```r
bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", rmarkdown::pdf_document(template="template.tex", keep_tex=TRUE))
```

I get a PDF where:

- The title and author are missing.
- The content (the result of `c1.Rmd` and `c2.Rmd`) is actually there.

By looking at `_index_merged.tex` (the generated TEX, which I can access since I specified `keep_tex=TRUE` inside `rmarkdown::pdf_document`), I can clearly see that:

- Placeholders `$title$` and `$author$` got replaced by empty strings, hence the empty title and author.
- Placeholder `$body$` got filled with content.

Here is (the relevant excerpt of) the content of `_index_merged.tex`:

```
...
\begin{document}

\author{ }
\title{}

\maketitle
...
```

Why is the template not correctly picking up the **title** and the **author**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bookdown, if you specify `rmd_files` in `_bookdown.yml`, only those files will be processed by bookdown. As your title and author are in the yaml header of `index.Rmd`, you need to include this file as well in `rmd_files`. Or add the yaml header in `c1.Rmd`

See about `rmd_files` behavior in [bookdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/usage.html#usage)